# On each column save of a model, save value of progress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called CommonApp, and a function on it, which generates a progress  %, based on how how much the user has filled in.

You can view the progress function here -->

```
 def progress
  total_questions = self.attribute_names.count + 2

  # +4 for name, cities,industries,positions, associated models
  # -4 for id,  created_at, updated_at, user_id these will always be filled anyways
  # +2 for video, associated model, but weighed more heavily

  total_completed = 0 

  self.attribute_names.each do |attr|
   total_completed += 1 unless self[attr].blank?
  end

  total_completed = total_completed - 3
  # +1 name ( on user table, not on here
  # -4 for id,  created_at, updated_at, user_id

  total_completed += 1 if self.cities.any?
  total_completed += 1 if self.positions.any?
  total_completed += 1 if self.industries.any?
  total_completed += 2 if self.user.video

  (100.0*total_completed/total_questions).round

 end
```

I would like to later sort by progress, so this implies to me that the best way to do it is to have a column in CommonApp called progress, and update the value of the column any time the progress changes.

How would I do that?

**Update**
I'm thinking of something more along the lines of below, which will update every time the progress function runs, and is different from the value of the progress column. But, I get the error --

```
undefined method `save!' for 93:Fixnum
```

This is the updated progress function

```
 def progress
  total_questions = self.attribute_names.count + 2

  # +4 for name, cities,industries,positions
  # -4 for id,  created_at, updated_at, user_id 
  # +2 for video 

  total_completed = 0 

  self.attribute_names.each do |attr|
   total_completed += 1 unless self[attr].blank?
  end

  total_completed = total_completed - 3
  # +1 name
  # -4 for id,  created_at, updated_at, user_id 

  total_completed += 1 if self.cities.any?
  total_completed += 1 if self.positions.any?
  total_completed += 1 if self.industries.any?
  total_completed += 2 if self.user.video

  value = (100.0*total_completed/total_questions).round 

  unless self.progress_level == value 
    self.progress_level = value
    self.save!
  end

  (100.0*total_completed/total_questions).round

 end
```

Comment: You could use a `before_action` filter to check the params and append/change a progress param accordingly (?).

Comment: You could use the Rails' observer module in order to observe the objects that increase/decrease the progress of a CommonApp, and updates the related progress value in the DB.

Comment: @MrYoshiji Observers officially deprecated in Rails 4.0. right?

Comment: Hey guys, added a quick update with an idea that would work inside the function, so I wouldn't need to track too much outside of the function itself. But, I do get an error. What do you think about it?

Comment: self.save! not self.progress_level.save!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column to the current model with a migration.

Update that columns whenever you run `progress`. Pretty much just like the way you're doing it now :-)

**Update**

Although I like the idea of doing this in a callback or an observer, I think you can get by with the way you're currently doing it. Callbacks and Observers can lead to misdirection. For this simple case I'd leave it in the method.